# jQuery fadeIn() should only show one div, is showing multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, show-hide

**UPDATE: Here's the Link**
http://15four.com/interactiveVideo/

OK, I am working on a project that is basically a "choose your own adventure" style video situation. The way it works is thus:

1. Play a video
2. set event listener for the "ended" state on the player
3. display a corresponding div with two buttons
4. User clicks one of the two buttons
5. load the corresponding video based on which button they clicked
6. Repeat

Everything works great on the first video. The div loads just fine, and clicking the button correctly loads and plays the next video. The problem is that when I reach the end of the *second* video, where It should display the *second* choose your own adventure div, it is displaying both the first AND second CYOA divs, with the second on top of the first.

Here is the JS function that displays the divs:

```
function loadModal(stage){
    var option1 = stage.modal.find("a.option1");
    var option2 = stage.modal.find("a.option2");

    var target1 = stage.option1;
    var target2 = stage.option2;

    stage.modal.fadeIn(1000);

    if(target1 != "div") {
        option1.click(function(){
            stage.modal.hide();
            console.log(target1);
            setMode(stages[target1]);
        });
    } else {
        setMode(stages.excite);
        video.pause();
    }
    if(target2 != "div") {
        option2.click(function(){
            stage.modal.hide();
            console.log(target2);
            setMode(stages[target2]);
        });
    } else {
        setMode(stages.excite);
        video.pause();
    }
}
```

And Here are the vars that contain all the data:

```
var i = 0;
var video = _V_("player");

var stages = {
                "excite":   {
                                "video": "vid/Clip_1.mov",
                                "modal": $('#exciteModal'),
                                "option1": "commit",
                                "option2": "compete"
                            },
                "commit":   {
                                "video": "vid/Clip_2.mov",
                                "modal": $('#commitModal'),
                                "option1": "div",
                                "option2": "compete",
                                "aside1": "pdf1",
                                "aside1": "iWill",
                                "aside1": "displayVis",

                            },
                "compete":  {
                                "video": "vid/Clip_3.mov",
                                "modal": $('#competeModal'),
                                "option1": "div",
                                "option2": "div",
                                "aside1": "pdf2",
                                "aside1": "salesChamp",
                                "aside1": "numberCrunch",
                            }
            };
```

And Finally: the markup for the divs

HTML

```
<div id="exciteModal" class="modals">
    <a class="option1" href="#1" data-target="commit">UA's Commitment</a>
    <a class="option2" href="#2" data-target="compete">Compete</a>
</div>
<div id="commitModal" class="modals">
    <a class="option1" href="#1" data-target="commit">Sign In</a>
    <a class="option2" href="#2" data-target="compete">Compete</a>
</div>
<div id="competeModal" class="modals">
    <a class="option1" href="#1" data-target="commit">Sign In</a>
    <a class="option2" href="#2" data-target="compete">Train</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#exciteModal, #commitModal, #competeModal {
  display: none; }

.modals {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -540px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 540px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 1000; }
  .modals a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 210px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the event listener I set for the ended event was not getting removed so the second time the ended event happened, there were two listeners listening for it.